# Where is a row appended in QStandardItemModel?

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

There is a method

```
void QStandardItemModel::appendRow(QStandardItem * item)
```

in class QStandardItemModel. I cannot figure out where the item is appended, or who the item's parent is after appending?

And another method

```
bool QStandardItemModel::insertRow(int row, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex())
```

shows the parent but which item will be appended to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is easy. As the name says: Append. It is appended to a list or a tree, which has only one column.

The second one is difficult. This function is not directly about inserting items, but about the algorithm **how** to insert items. In a complicated tree this is not a necessarily trivial task. Adding nodes, changing the dimension of a tree. You have to implement this virtual method, when you have to create an editable tree. In that case making room for a new item and actually inserting the item are two different tasks.